# Does anyone know a Socks5 server I can run in OsX which allows chaining to an HTTP proxy?

Tags: macos, proxy, socks

Does anyone know of an OSX (Lion) Socks5 proxy that allows chaining to an HTTP(s) proxy with authentication?  I've been searching the web, but can't seem to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of searching around, and I finally found [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) which works quite well.  There is a slight build problem with v0.92.3 when compiling with Lion and XCode 4.5.1 - there is a make error that it does not recognize "-Wno-unused-but-set-variable".  Just comment out that warning from the Makefile, and it compiles and runs well.